# Winter Bash 2016 : Not Getting received 011-Hat for "Collect 11 hats" action

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Not getting received **011 Hat** for ***"Collect 11 hats"*** action, even though I have already collected 12 hats for SQA site.

[image: image1]

---

> Is this valid bug with SQA beta site or there is something new steps to collect **011-Hat**?

[image]

Comment: Where should I get answer of this question??

Comment: I'm not sure, Bharat. Looks like it just only looks for them every so often, because you appear to now have the hat.

Comment: You don't have any hats at all.